# grep and ls command passing to a bin executable

Tags: linux, bash, grep, sh, ls

I need some help with this little script in sh
I want to find all files in the script directory that have STR in filename and pass to a program.
Everything works well apart the last file that give me a file not found in the program...

```
files=$( ls | grep STR)
for file in $files;  do ./epk2extract "$file" -a 0x1C -v 0x1B;  done
```

I hope someone could help me
Best regards
Stefano

Comment: *find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '\*STR\*' -exec ./epk2extract {} -a 0x1C -v 0x1B \;*

Comment: @alecxs Use \` backtick characters to write code formatted `with monospaced font like this`.

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs is required reading.

Answer (score 2):

Your handling of strings is prone to errors caused by spaces in file names. Standard shell expansions, when used correctly, can get the token boundaries right for you, even when file names contain spaces:

```sh
files=(*STR*)
for file in "${files[@]}"; do ./epk2extract "$file" -a 0x1C -v 0x1B; done
```

If you insist on running `ls` (which is unnecessary) or on obtaining the file names from a command output (which may be useful), then:

```sh
readarray -t files < <(ls | grep STR)
for file in "${files[@]}"; do ./epk2extract "$file" -a 0x1C -v 0x1B; done
```

Answer (score 0):

With ls and whitespaces

```
awk '{print "./epk2extract \"" $0 "\" -a 0x1C -v 0x1B;"}' <<<$(ls *STR*)|sh
```